# Backgroundprocess for timebased operations

Tags: c#, timer, .net-2.0

i have an application (.Net Framework 2.0!) where you can enter operations which will be executed at a given time.

Now i want to create a process which runs in background and does nothing else then waiting till the given time is reached and call the operation to run. The application should run things like making backup of specific parts of the computer, start updates, run batches, ... The backgroundworker will run over several month doing nothing else.

Using the code below would work but it seems a bit ugly. Is there any better solution?

```
while(true && !applicationClosing)
{

    List<ExecProcess> processList = LoadStoredProcesses();
    List<ExecProcess> spawnedProcesses = new List<ExecProcess>();

    DateTime actualTime = DateTime.Now();

    foreach(ExecProcess ep in processList)
    {
       if(ep.ExecutionTime < actualTime)
       {
           ep.Execute();
           spawnedProcesses.Add(ep);
       }
    }

    RemoveSpawnedProcesses(spawnedProcesses);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
```

Thank you verry much.

Comment: A better solution would be to use the Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: I dont want to use the Windows Task Scheduler. Shortly: Im implementing a extended Windows Task Scheduler which allows to run and manage my own applications.

Comment: How about using a windows service that can pick up items from a messagequeue. e.g. new tasks are sent to queue, service picks up and queues it internally.

Comment: I dont need a messagequeue cause the execution plan and the parameter for the execution are stored in a database where i can take them easily of. But i will take a look at the services and the messagequeues i never used them before. My biggest problem is "only" how i get my programm to react at a defined time. Is there nothing like: Clock.SetNextAlarm = ep.ExecutionTime; Clock.Alarm += new AlarmEventHandler(RunNextProgramm); And then theres nothing todo cause windows will fire the event in case the time i set is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Windows service` which implements a timer that fires an event every n seconds. You can pickup your tasks from wherever you want, and queue them internally in the service and fire at given times. Just check the timestamps within the `_executeTimer_Elapsed` method. This is only a small sample, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{

    private Timer _executeTimer;
    private bool _isRunning;

    public MyService()
    {
        _executeTimer = new Timer();
        _executeTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60; // 1 minute
        _executeTimer.Elapsed += _executeTimer_Elapsed;
        _executeTimer.Start();
    }

    private void _executeTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isRunning) return; // logic already running, skip out.

        try
        {
            _isRunning = true; // set timer event running.

            // perform some logic.

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // perform some error handling. You should be aware of which 
            // exceptions you can handle and which you can't handle. 
            // Blanket handling Exception is not recommended.
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _isRunning = false; // set timer event finished.  
        }
    }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // perform some startup initialization here.
        _executeTimer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // perform shutdown logic here.
        _executeTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```